# Font Awesome 5 with Angular

Tags: angular, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, angular-fontawesome

How do I use [font-awesome **5**](https://fontawesome.com/) with Angular (2+)?

I've tried adding this inside a component:

```js
import {faChevronLeft, faChevronRight} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid';
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';
...
constructor(){
   fontawesome.library.add(faChevronLeft, faChevronRight);
}
```

and then in HTML:

```html
<span class="fa" [class.fa-chevron-left]="direction==='left'" [class.fa-chevron-right]="direction==='right'"></span>
```

But this gives me a blinking question mark in a circle.

Comment: https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome

Comment: "This project is not yet production-ready. It's basically an elaborate "hello world" of FA5 icons, presented with an Angular component, using the Font Awesome 5 API." Also, it is not published in NPM.

Comment: Note: I installed it with npm

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You have two options:

---

### 1. Use angular-fontawesome library

Just follow the instructions on their [github page](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome).

---

### 2. Use fontawesome 5 directly

Make sure you have installed all the relevant [npm packages](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/js-component-packages).
For Pro packages check out [this](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js#pro).

1. Import relevant icons:

   ```js
   import {faChevronLeft, faChevronRight} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid';
   import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';
   ```
2. Add the icons to `fontawesome` library **in global scope** (not inside the component's constructor):

   ```js
   fontawesome.library.add(faChevronLeft, faChevronRight);
   ```
3. Use it in html:

   ```html
   <span class="fas" [class.fa-chevron-left]="direction==='left'" [class.fa-chevron-right]="direction==='right'"></span>
   ```
4. Mind the prefixes in html:

   - `fas` for `fontawesome-free-solid` icons (works also with `fa`)

     ```html
     <span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span>
     ```
   - `fab` for `fontawesome-free-brands` icons

     ```html
     <span class="fab fa-bitcoin"></span>
     ```
   - `far` for `fontawesome-free-regular` icons

     ```html
     <span class="far fa-chevron-left"></span>
     ```
   - `fal` for `fontawesome-free-light` icons (pro)

     ```html
     <span class="fal fa-chevron-left"></span>
     ```

**Important note:**

It's fine to use variables to define `fontawesome` classes as soon as it is done only once (at initialization). However, if the variable changes its value it won't be reflected in html.
Consider this example:

```html
<span class="fas fa-chevron-{{direction}}"></span>
```

This will put the right icon at the initialization time, but if the direction changes afterwards it won't be reflected.
The reason for this is that `fontawesome 5` replaces the elements classed with `fa ...` with appropriate `svg` and once it is replaced no variable affects this.
If you want the above html to reflect runtime changes you have to change it like this:

```html
<span *ngIf="direction==='right'"><span class="fas fa-chevron-right"></span></span>
<span *ngIf="direction==='left'"><span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span></span>
```

The outer `span` is necessary as the inner `span` is replaced with `svg` so you can't put `*ngIf` on it.

**Further reading**:

- [Use fontawesome 5 with node.js](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js)
- [FontAwesome API](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/font-awesome-api)

Comment: If you want to keep the DOM a little cleaner, you can wrap the icon element inside an ng-container instead of a span. for example, <ng-container *ngIf="direction==='right"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></ng-container>

Comment: in response to my above comment, this is limited to when you only need the ngIf to evaluate once (on load), if the icon state is going to be dynamic, youll have to keep a span tag around it, as it will remain in the DOM, unlike the ng-container. in my app i have an 'X' icon that appears when a search input has a value. that value is a 2-way bound [(ngModel)] so span must be used in place of ng-container.

Comment: "This project is a work in progress, not yet production ready." - Is the readme just not updated or? :)

Comment: Dave, without a <span></span> wrapped around the <i> angular won't "track" the generated contents and every time the icon is changed a new svg will be generated. It needs a wrapper element.

Comment: Suggestion to wrap span within a span was a life-saver for preserving my angular (click) event on the (now) outer span, as well as keeping a growing stack of icons from accumulating with each click on other spans. Hope that makes sense. In plain English... THANK YOU!

Comment: What do you mean by `Add the icons to fontawesome library in global scope`?

Comment: Meaning not inside the class. Right after the imports or similar.

Comment: Man - i love you! You solved my 3 days struggle with angular :D

Comment: how to do it in angular-cli 6

Comment: I tried to use angular-font-awesome and it is based on an old version on font-awesome and it appears some of the icons are missing.

Comment: @Andy Clark *angular-fontawesome* doesn't contain icons. You install it along with *fontawesome* library. Probably you installed the core icons but forgot to install the other ones. There are *free-solid-svg-icons*, *free-brands-svg-icons*, *free-regular-svg-icons* and more *pro* icons. It is all specified on their github page.

Comment: @meltedspark Somehow I found myself using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome. I will try again with the link in your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 48):

The simplest way is to install it through npm and then import the styles:

1)

```
npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save
```

2) Import the styles in **angular.json**

```
"styles": [
  ...
  "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
  ...
]
```

And then you can use it as it is in their [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)

```
<i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
```

Comment: Working like a charm. Thanks !

Comment: Clean and easy.

Comment: I suppose that tree shaking would not work in this case

Comment: One thing I would add (which I wish I knew) is to always restart you app after modifying angular.json. If you are using an IDE always 'Stop' then 'Run'.

Answer (score 4):

**I am using Font Awesome 5 in Angular**

**This is HTML code**

```
<fa-icon [icon]="isFavorite ? ['fas','star'] : ['far','star']" (click)="onClick()"> Star </fa-icon>
```

**This is my Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'favorite',
  templateUrl: './favorite.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favorite.component.css']
})
export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {
isFavorite: boolean;
  prefix:string;
  constructor() { }    
  ngOnInit() { }

  onClick(){
    this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;    
  }
}
`
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: How can I get the icon name from a function?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to render FontAwesome 5 in Angular using either WebFont or SVG:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ui4ngx/fontawesome

[Demo](https://tuyenttran.github.io/ngx-fontawesome/)

This uses HTML templates instead of Javascript rendering
It provides the same features as angular-fontawesome library does

For older version (v4), you can use this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ui4ngx/fontawesome4

[Demo](https://tuyenttran.github.io/ngx-fontawesome4/)