# fontawsome angular only class fa working not fas or

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I've integrated fontsawsome in

my angular project like

### styles.scss

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

**it doesn't work**

```
<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
<i class="far fa-user"></i>
<i class="fab fa-user"></i>
```

**it works**

```
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
```

so what's the matter?

### UPDATE

I found the problem

with

**npm install fontawsome**

you get the 4.7 version for the 5 version

you should run

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands
```

take a look at

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027322/font-awesome-5-with-angular

Comment: Do you use pro or free?

Comment: I'm using the free version

Answer (score 0):

You should check you font awesome version.

`<i class="fa fa-user"></i>` is used for old 4.7.0 version, while

```
<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
<i class="far fa-user"></i>
<i class="fab fa-user"></i>
```

is used for newer  5.0 and up version.

Comment: I believe `fa` still works, to make it easier for people to switch to 5.