# FontAwesome not working with Angular using spans

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular-fontawesome

I am new to Angular, so bear with me.
I am trying to use FontAwesome in my project. Initially I had it loaded via CDN, but I want to use it properly.
So I have imported the `FontAwesomeModule` into my `WidgetModule`. Which looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { WidgetRoutingModule } from './widget-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from '@pyb-shared/shared.module';
import { WidgetComponent } from './widget.component';
import { ScenariosComponent } from './scenarios/scenarios.component';
import { QuestionsComponent } from './questions/questions.component';
import { AnswersComponent } from './answers/answers.component';
import { ResultsComponent } from './results/results.component';

import { AnswerButtonComponent } from './shared/answer-button/answer-button.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/header/header.component';
import { LoadingButtonComponent } from './shared/loading-button/loading-button.component';
import { MainProductComponent } from './shared/main-product/main-product.component';
import { MatchesComponent } from './shared/matches/matches.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './shared/product/product.component';
import { QuestionSplitComponent } from './shared/question-split/question-split.component';

import { AnswersService } from './answers/answers.service';
import { QuestionsService } from './questions/questions.service';
import { ResultsService } from './results/results.service';
import { ScenariosService } from './scenarios/scenarios.service';

import { AnswerMatchService } from './shared/answer-match.service';
import { DuplicateService } from './shared/duplicate.service';
import { FilterService } from './shared/filter.service';
import { FormulaService } from './shared/formula.service';
import { MatchesService } from './shared/matches.service';
import { PickService } from './shared/pick.service';
import { QuestionSplitService } from './shared/question-split/question-split.service';
import { StateService } from './shared/state.service';
import { WidgetService } from './widget.service';

import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faSquare, faCheckSquare } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    WidgetRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    WidgetComponent,
    ScenariosComponent,
    QuestionsComponent,
    AnswersComponent,
    ResultsComponent,

    AnswerButtonComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LoadingButtonComponent,
    MainProductComponent,
    MatchesComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    QuestionSplitComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AnswersService,
    QuestionsService,
    ResultsService,
    ScenariosService,

    AnswerMatchService,
    DuplicateService,
    FilterService,
    FormulaService,
    MatchesService,
    PickService,
    QuestionSplitService,
    StateService,
    WidgetService
  ]
})
export class WidgetModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log('WidgetModule loaded.');
    library.add(faSquare, faCheckSquare);
  }
}
```

I want to show two icons on my component, so you can see in the module above I have added **faSquare** and **faCheckSquare**.
In my component (which is called **ScenariosComponent**), I just have this span:

```
<span class="fas fa-square"></span>
```

From the link I provided above, and looking at this:

https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome

It looks like it should work.
I have the **FontAwesomeModule** imported, the **ScenariosComponent** has the **WidgetModule** as its parent module, so it should just work.
According to this line:

> Icons added to the library will be available to any other component whose parent module also imports FontAwesomeModule.

And I do have my library set up in my module. Which should work within that module, at least in my understanding.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Do you have a `pro-licensed` version? You seem to be using icons that are a part of the pro version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use [**`angular-fontawesome`**](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#get-started), you'll have to follow their guide. There are a few issues with your implementation.

The first issue is here:

```
import { faSquare, faCheckSquare } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';
```

You're importing from `@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons` which is a pro version of FortAwesome.

You should have imported from `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons` instead:

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faSquare, faCheckSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

Then in your AppModule:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    library.add(faSquare, faCheckSquare);
  }
}
```

The second issue is, from the Guide for [**`angular-fontawesome`**](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#get-started), it seems that you'll have to use it as a Component: **`fa-icon`** which has an `@Input` property **`[icon]`** to which you'll have to supply the name of the class(es) you want to apply to them.

Something like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'square']"></fa-icon>
  <br>
  <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'check-square']"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-font-awesome-starter?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: thanks for your reply :) I have linked the pro version on purpose, we have a license (which I have registered). I know I can do it the way you have stated, but I would prefer not to use them as components. I tried to follow this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027322/font-awesome-5-with-angular but it didn't work