# font-awesome doesn't work can someone help me?

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I am trying `<i class="fas fa-user-plus" *ngIf="!loggedIn"></i>`

But I don't receive any image. here is what i receive:

[image: Here is what i received]

I did install font-awesome from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome#get-started
step by step .

```
"styles": ["node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Awesome 5 with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027322/font-awesome-5-with-angular)

Answer (score 0):

Usage section at the link you provided suggests to use like this

```
 <fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

The package you installed does not contain:

```
"node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"
```

Use the following path instead:

```
"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
```

Comment: I don't have in node_modules @fortawesome

Comment: "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
I have this in my package

Comment: @Marius you should have it if you successfully installed it. Try this again: `npm i @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome`